# Getting Error:VM Exception while processing transaction: revert', 'code': -32000. when deploying to Ganache using Web3.py

Tags: remix, ganache, web3.py, python

I get the following error message:
Getting Error:VM Exception while processing transaction: revert', 'code': -32000
I am connected to Ganache. Here is my code:

```
import json
from web3 import Web3
ganache_url = "HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(ganache_url))
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]
abi = json.loads('[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_greeting","type":"string"}],"name":"setGreeting","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"greet","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"greeting","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"}]')
bytecode = "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"
Greeter = web3.eth.contract(abi=abi,bytecode=bytecode)
tx_hash=Greeter.constructor().transact()
```

This is my Solidity contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;
contract Greeter {
    string public greeting;
    function Greeter () public {
        greeting ="Hello";
    }
    function setGreeting (string _greeting ) public {
        greeting = _greeting;
    }
    function greet()view public returns (string){
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

The last statement: `tx_hash=Greeter.constructor().transact()` doesn't compile.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance :)

Edit: Added a ")" at web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(ganache_url)) according to Majd TL's suggestion.

Comment: are you missing a ")" after web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(ganache_url) ?

Comment: Yes I do. Edited it :)
However, in my original code it is there, so apparently I deleted it while copying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I figured it out:
My solidity code had some problems. Using this one compiling with 0.5.7 worked.

```
   pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

    contract MessageContract{
        string private message = "Hello World";

        function getMessage() public view returns(string memory){
           return message;
        }

        function setMessage(string memory newMessage ) public {
           message = newMessage;
        }
    }
```